# Tkinter Call function when Entry box is clicked?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is it possible to call a function when the user clicks onto an Entry box in Tkinter?

I have a help system which allows you to click help and then on a button and it brings up a window for that button describing what it does. I have not, however, been able to find a way of doing it for an Entry box.

Comment: Do you literally mean only when they click, or should the function be called whenever the widget gets the keyboard focus (eg: when the user presses tab from another widget)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call a function whenever a widget is clicked on, you simply need to bind a function to the click event. For example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def handle_click(event):
    print("clicked!")

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack(fill="x")

entry.bind("<1>", handle_click)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you this works. Can you explain what the "<1>" means?

Comment: @Frogboxe: it represents the button 1 click event.  It is shorthand for `<ButtonPress-1>`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to call a function when the user clicks onto an Entry
> box in Tkinter?

Yes, you can click when you're finished. Using `entry.bind("<Return>"`

```
import tkinter as tk

def handle_click(event):
    x = entry.get()
    print(x)

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack(fill="x")

entry.bind("<Return>", handle_click)

root.mainloop()
```